# Why is nothing loading in my android/data/<package-name> folders?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-file, android-12, android-storage

Why can't I find anything inside the default app data folders (like Android/data/com.google......)? Whenever I try to find anything inside any of those folders, it just shows loading and loading(like loading for infinity), but it never loads up . What's the problem..!? And how do I fix it..?!?

Bellow, you can see that I was trying to find the default download folder of the app "Happy Mod"

[image: Happy Mod apk default download path]

[image: Files by Google(Home)]

## **In the SD card**

[image: in Sd card]

[image: Just loading & loading]

## **In the Internal storage**

[image: in the Internal storage, it’s just empty]

*I tried to view them using other apps from playstore. But none of them worked! some just freez when I open any of those folders and some show them empty!!*

**But when I used my pc to view those, I could see all the files were there(In the Internal Storage!!). Then why are those not showing up on my phone!! What's the problem..!!**

## Internal shared storage\Android\data\

[image: Internal storage\Android\data]

## Internal storage\Android\data\com.happymod.apk\files\Download\

[[image: Internal storage\Android\data\com.happymod.apk\files\Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIjeH.png)]